# aws s3api listing not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to list content by using `aws s3api` for listing bucket content. I

`aws s3api list-objects --bucket user_list_staging`

When I run it it gets stuck, does not return anything neither return prompt but when I do `aws s3 ls s3://user_list_staging` it returns the content.

The reason I want to use `s3api` to paginate my query and get Next Token which I don't find in `aws s3 ls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Couple things that can help.

```
--debug (boolean)
```

Turn on debug logging.

will add some debug output to let you know what is going on,

Also

> If you see issues when running list commands on a large number of
>   resources, the default page size may be too high, causing calls to AWS
>   services to time out.

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --page-size 100
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the page size does not actually affect the number of items returned in the output; therefore it will not actually help if the result size is too large.  You'll need to use --max-items which does limit the number of items returned.

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --max-items 100
```